# Play Framework in GAE not taking routes

Tags: playframework

I created a simple play application.  I am planning to host the app in Google App Engine.  I have completed testing of the application in my local machine.  I deployed successfully (without any deployment errors) to Google cloud.

Problem: After deployment to Google's cloud, my requests are not handled through Play's routes file.  I need some suggestions

I am using Play 1.2.5, gae module 1.6.0, appengine-java-sdk-1.7.5

Here is my routes file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
#GET     /                                       Application.index

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path


GET     /v1/items                   com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.listItems()
POST    /v1/items                   com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.createItem()
PUT     /v1/items                   com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.updateItems()
DELETE  /v1/items                   com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.deleteItems()

GET     /v1/items/{pId}             com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.getItem
POST    /v1/items/{pId}             com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.unsupportedRequest
PUT     /v1/items/{pId}             com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.updateItem
DELETE  /v1/items/{pId}             com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.deleteItem

GET     /v1/requirements            com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.listRequirements()
POST    /v1/requirements            com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.createRequirement()
PUT     /v1/requirements            com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.updateRequirement()
DELETE  /v1/requirements            com.github.mygrocery.controller.MyGroceryController.deleteRequirements()

# Catch all
GET     /                           staticDir:public

*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: did you find any solution for this ? i guess your root route "/" is mapped to staticDir:public thats why nothing is working

Comment: There was an error in PUT request handling method.  Though this error has been fixed, I did not get a chance to look into why this was occurring.

Comment: so are you saying that when you fixed PUT method, this problem vanished ?